# Gauge degrees of freedom in Schwinger model

Tags: gauge-theory, boundary-conditions, lattice-model, lattice-gauge-theory

Schwinger model is the (1+1)-D QED. The number of gauge degrees of freedom (DOF) after the gauge fixing of the Schwinger model depends on the boundary condition of the model. For example, one can eliminate the gauge completely with open boundary conditions while it is not possible to do so in a periodic boundary condition, i.e., there remains one gauge DOF. I want to understand how the gauge DOF depends on the boundary condition for the Schwinger model.

P.S. In the Hamiltonian formulation of the lattice U(1) gauge theory in 1+1-D, it is said that the Gauss law eliminates the remaining gauge DOF for open BC (e.g. see page 6 of [this article](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/aa89ab)) but not for periodic BC.

Comment: I think this paper "Charged Boundary States in the Schwinger Model" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.04683v1) could help. From quickly skimming over it: One component of the gauge field is usually eliminated using gauge fixing. With open boundary conditions it is possible to remove the last remaining component using the equation of motion for the gauge field. With periodic boundary conditions the latter is not possible.

Comment: Often mentioned by which lattice simulations? Which reference? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic I meant lattice simulations using the Hamiltonian formulation of U(1) gauge theory. However, I now understand that the # of gauge DOF comes from the continuum model, not from the lattice. So, I have changed my question. The main question remains the same though, how do boundary conditions change the # of DOF? How can Gauss law eliminate the gauge DOF for open BC but not for periodic BC?